# How to change Pandas Column Values in List Format

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to multiply each value in a column by 0.01 but the column values are in list format. How do I apply it to each element of the list in each row? For example, my data looks like this:

```
ID          Amount
156    [14587, 38581, 55669]
798    [67178, 98635]
```

And I'm trying to multiply each element in the lists by 0.01.

```
ID          Amount
156    [145.87, 385.81, 556.69]
798    [671.78, 986.35]
```

I've tried the following code but got an error message saying "can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'".

```
df['Amount'] = df3['Amount'].apply(lambda x: x*0.00000001 in x)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need another loop / list comprehension in `apply`:

```
df['Amount'] = df.Amount.apply(lambda lst: [x * 0.01 for x in lst])
df

    ID                    Amount
0  156  [145.87, 385.81, 556.69]
1  798          [671.78, 986.35]
```